# Yii - Saving MANY_MANY relationship in Form?

Tags: php, yii, many-to-many

I have a 3 tables, contact, group and contact_group.

All the model relations are set up appropriately:

Contact.php

```
'groups' => array(self::MANY_MANY, 'Group', 'contact_group(contact_id,group_id)'),
```

Group.php

```
'contacts' => array(self::MANY_MANY, 'Contact', 'contact_group(group_id,contact_id)'),
```

If I manually create the relationship, I can query them just fine using Yii's Active Record.

---

What I am trying to accomplish is building a form so that when a user creates a contact, they can assign the contact to a group in the beginning.  My form looks like this:

```
<?php echo $form->dropDownListRow($model, 'groups', Group::getActiveGroups(), array('multiple'=>true)); ?>
```

This displays perfectly, with all the groups showing up how I want.  When the users selects a group or two, they get submitted.  I was hoping that was all I had to do to save the user in the `contact_group` table but it doesn't do that.  I can launch an `afterSave` event to handle the insert, but just wanted to check if there was anything that Yii does to handle this by itself.

Comment: you may use ext 1) http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/save-relations-ar-behavior/ 2) http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/cadvancedarbehavior/

Comment: Or I just program it myself....  Yii doesn't have a way to handle it is what you are saying.